# Powershell doesn't parse date

Tags: powershell

I have string with date that I need to parse, but `ParseExact` set to variable nothing. This is my code:

```
$timeString1="6/18/2014 6:41:09 PM"
$culture = Get-Culture
$format = "M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt"
$date1 = [DateTime]::ParseExact($timeString1, $format, $culture)#date1=""
```

If I remove PM, it successful parse:

```
$timeString1="6/18/2014 6:41:09"
$culture = Get-Culture
$format = "M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss"
$date1 = [DateTime]::ParseExact($timeString1, $format, $culture)
```

So how it's fix that parse with PM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example works well on my computer. Check what culture you pass to `ParseExact`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32> $timeString1="6/18/2014 6:41:09 PM"
$culture = Get-Culture
$format = "M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt"
$date1 = [DateTime]::ParseExact($timeString1, $format, $culture)

PS C:\WINDOWS\System32> $date1

Wednesday, June 18, 2014 18:41:09



PS C:\WINDOWS\System32> Get-Culture

LCID             Name             DisplayName                                           
----             ----             -----------                                           
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```